# Yum error CentOS 6.7, can't get connected to the package http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release_rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm

Tags: centos6, yum, packages

I tried `yum clean all` and `yum update` and then I try `yum erase apf` and yum erase doesn't work because it can't get connected to the package mentioned in a title.
I am connected to the internet and everything seems to work normally without yum. I have done my research and I come up with the solution of getting those packages from another resource. So I tried also `wget` with some other package but it doesn't work and it says

> packages.sw.be|78.46.17.228|:80... failed: Connection timed out

This is my `yum.conf`:

[image]

And this is my `yum.repos.d`:

[image]

And this is happening when I insert `yum whatprovides will`

> Loaded plugins: priorities
> $URL/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
>
> Trying other mirror.
> Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: repoforgeextras. Please verify its path and try again

My best clue is `yum.repos.d` and its base path.

Comment: Does rpmforge even exist anymore? It has been not recommended for a long time...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am a newbie in CentOS. Could You recommend some other package ? Anyhow I have installed it with Vagrant and it just gave that image, with that package pre-installed. Could You describe to me how should I change this package ?